# Kivy (Python 3 GUI library) shows two white dots/circles/cursers that mess up prototyping

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have installed the kivy pie distro (http://kivypie.mitako.eu/) on my raspberry pi, to begin working on kivy for Android development in python. Everything now works (figured out you have to enable OpenGL with full kms to make it work "properly") I just have stumbled on a problem with prototyping. Two (and sometimes even three) dots/cursors ([Click here to view how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8s8D.png)) appear. The program counts these all as cursors, so I sometimes accidentally click more than one button, or I have to hold the left mouse key in order to type into text boxes, etc... This makes it really frustrating to prototype my projects, especially with advanced widgets such as carousel. I know it is a problem with how kivy is set up, not my code, as:
1.It appears in all my projects, 2. It functions very well on Android, after building an apk with buuldozer, and 3. For testing purpuses, I copied the project from Dusty Philips' "Creating Apps In Kivy", published by O'Reilly.

Here is the log:

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-09-26_0.txt
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.0
[INFO   ] Python: v3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1]
[INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: egl_rpi
[INFO   ] OSC: using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] GL: Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] GL: Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL version <b'2.1 Mesa 13.0.0'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL renderer <b'Gallium 0.4 on VC4 V3D 2.1'>
[INFO   ] GL: OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] GL: Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max size <2048>
[INFO   ] GL: Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] Window: auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] Window: virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] Clipboard: Provider: xclip(['clipboard_dbusklipper', 'clipboard_gtk3'] ignored)
[INFO   ] CutBuffer: cut buffer support enabled
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event1
[INFO   ] MTD: Read event from </dev/input/event1>
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event2
[INFO   ] MTD: Read event from </dev/input/event2>
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] MTD: Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event1
[INFO   ] HIDInput: Read event from </dev/input/event1>
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event2
[INFO   ] HIDInput: Read event from </dev/input/event2>
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] HIDInput: Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event1
[INFO   ] HIDInput: Read event from </dev/input/event1>
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event2
[INFO   ] HIDInput: Read event from </dev/input/event2>
[INFO   ] ProbeSysfs: device match: /dev/input/event0
[INFO   ] HIDInput: Read event from </dev/input/event0>
[INFO   ] Base: Start application main loop
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range position X is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event2> range position X is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event1> range position X is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: using <b'Plus More Enterprise LTD. USB-compliant keyboard\x00'>
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: using <b'Plus More Enterprise LTD. USB-compliant keyboard\x00'>
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: using <b'Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)\x00'>
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: using <b'Plus More Enterprise LTD. USB-compliant keyboard\x00'>
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: using <b'Plus More Enterprise LTD. USB-compliant keyboard\x00'>
[INFO   ] HIDMotionEvent: using <b'Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)\x00'>
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range position Y is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] GL: NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event1> range position Y is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event2> range position Y is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event1> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event2> range touch major is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event1> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event2> range touch minor is 0 - 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event1> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event2> range pressure is 0 - 255
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event0> rotation set to 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event1> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event2> axes invertion: X is 0, Y is 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event2> rotation set to 0
[INFO   ] MTD: </dev/input/event1> rotation set to 0
[INFO   ] Base: Leaving application in progress...
```

Edit: This Happens On All my Screens. ASUS , Raspberry Pi official touchscreen, and a LG tv.

Comment: I am using kivy on raspbian. I do not have any dots, but I also do not have any cursor. I am using the official touchscreen. So if you do not need the mouse, this could be an option

Comment: This will not work as 1: It still clicks in a random place, and 2: Fixing it to work like it does on a phone is not an option, as it is highly inconvenient to look at that small screen and code.